# Oracle blob - inserting long (over 4000 hex-digits) data in sql command

Tags: sql, oracle, blob

How can I, in Oracle 11, insert large data (~100000 hex-digits) into Blob field, **using sql command only** (without any external data with `load` cluase or such).

```
update tablename set fieldname='AA';
```

Works - 1 byte;

```
update tablename set fieldname='AA...(4000 hex-digits)...AA';
```

Doesn't. Niether `Concat` helps; strings can't be larger than 4000 chars. Is there other way, using sql command only?

Comment: Are you insistent that it must be SQL - would an block of self-contained pl/sql be acceptable? And are we talking SQL*Plus as a client?? (Strings can be 32k in Ora 10 in some client languages). I think you want something like a PL/SQL block, combined with HEXTORAW to populate a BLOB variable, then update using the BLOB.

Comment: Where does the hex data come from?  An OS file or something like that?  Fundamentally there isn't a way to squeeze a literal exceeding 4000 characters into a SQL statement.  However, there are workarounds if you have some wriggle room.  We need more details, specifically WRT the reasons underlying the requirement for "using sql command only"

Comment: Just to add to @APC comment the statement you have "fieldname='AA...'" really is VARCHAR2 to the SQL and hence the restriction of 4K. You are leveraging Oracle's implicit type casting which you should avoid really.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it is not possible. What you can do is:

1. select blob from table
2. get blob from resultset
3. get outputstream from blob
4. write to stream
5. flush and update blob in table
6. commit

You should be able to replace steps 1-2 by creating a temporary blob and using that for writing and updating.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE
  buf RAW(100000);
BEGIN
  buf := hextoraw('626567696E2030207575656E636F64652E6275660D0A6');
  UPDATE tableName SET columnName = buf;
  --or
  INSERT INTO tableName(charColumn, BlobColumn) values ('Sting', buf);
END;
```